# jbpm form builder's "IO Data" search is displaying processes only from default package

Tags: builder, jbpm, drools-guvnor, form-designer, formbuilder

**Problem**:

I have form builder embedded in guvnor. When I create a new form definition within from guvnor, and provide the package for the form definition, still I can't see processes from that package. The only processes that I can get in that search are conming from DEFAULT package.

**Expectation**:

I want to get processes only from the package which I have provided in popup screen while creating form definition.

**Environment**:

I am using drools-guvnor 5.4.0.Final with jbpm-form-builder.war downloaded from the following path.

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/jbpm/jbpm-form-builder-distribution/5.4.0.Final/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the processes from the package follow the following steps ,

i.  Create a form without any process attachment
ii. Save it
iii.    Then again open it and  press Search
iv. Processes from the selected package will appear

This issue was first reported and fixed in Version 5.2 as stated in the below jboss JIRA issues.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-3157#comment-12777068